# Databinding to cells

Tags: c#, wpf

I can easily bind that object list to the grid having each object represent one row. I never did a databinding having the objects represent cells. The question is, can this be achieved using WPF.

I have an observable list of objects and each object shall be represented a cell in a grid. The row and column is given by properties of the class.

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve

Let's assume I have a class with the following properties:

```
string Salesman
string Country
int    Profit
```

I want to bind that to a grid (or whatever is appropriate for this) having the salesmans as rows and the countries as columns.

In this example I have four objects in my ObservableList.

```
         US      Canada     Mexico 
Steve    11        23         
Enrico                        22 
Pete     13
```

If this cannot be done, the The alternative would be to transform the list into objects that can represent rows (i my example: salesman objects having all the countries as properties )

Comment: What is your question really? Are you asking us to code this for you? Where is your current attempt and the code you have used for the objects?

Comment: Yes, it can. And please stop deleting your comments immediately.

Comment: I have updated the question. Sorry I deleted the comment, because I hit ENTER to early.  And NO, I do not want someone to Code this for me. I would appreciate if someone can Point me to the right direction (Keywords for instance)  Thank you

Comment: You know I get notifications for every comment you submit? :) You really need to show more, since now it reads like a tutorial request, which is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

Most third party controls does this kind of support.

My experience with Devexpress is:

1. Bind distinct countries to columns collection of data grid
2. All columns must be unbound columns
3. Every cell will provide Get and Set methods.

Using the above steps I was able to achieve this. But with poor performance.

If you wish to do it with simple WPF Datagrid you still have unbound column I guess but follow same steps and use other combination of events if you want